# Is it possible to store a frequently used query in OData as a report in Microsoft Dataverse?

Tags: odata, powerapps, dataverse

I have a MS Dataverse query which uses OData to grab a bunch of data from an MS Power App (yes I know).

The OData query is about 800 characters long and is rather cumbersome with a lot of joins and nested selects etc.

My query is always going to be the same, so what I want to do store it as a report or set of pre-populated parameters, so then my OData query is just requesting that report, allowing me to cut the number of characters in the API call to a minimum.

If I was programming properly, and not using this annoying low-code stuff, then I'd name that an API Endpoint. A defined contract that always produces the same data every time. I would give my Endpoint a name like "GetUserData" and that's what I would use.

Is setting up something like this possible in OData / Dataverse, or am I doomed to pass in a huge query string as parameters every single time?

I've searched all over StackOverflow and google etc but the combination of "OData" and "Report" or "Query" just sends me down endless PowerBI rabbit holes.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a custom API, custom API are described here
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/developer/data-platform/custom-api

practically you encapsulate your code inside the custom API and you just call the custom API (you can also define input parameters) in order to get the result (by using an output parameter).

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the complexity of the odata query, you could also just save this as a Personal View using [Advanced Find](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/user/advanced-find)